# How to EnableDHCP and delete IP from adapter via WMI

Tags: c#

Im making some kind of IP setting tool and i have a problem with EnableDHCP method via WMI (Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration). Adapter was set to DHCP but there is still IP and gateway. So i am using netsh function which works to me but i want to use only WMI. Any advice?

I try some methods like Lease and send null to static but it doesnt work.

```
                s//THIS ONE I WANT TO USE BUT ITS LET IP AT ADAPTER EVEN DHCP IS ENABLED

    public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ManagementClass objMC = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMC.GetInstances();
        //check numbe of aktive ports

            foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
            {

                if ((bool)objMO["IPEnabled"])
                {

                try
                {
                    // write parameters to active port
                    ManagementBaseObject setIP;
                    setIP = objMO.InvokeMethod("EnableDHCP", null, null);
                }
                catch (Exception x)
                {

                }                   
                }               
            }
    }





                                        Process p = new Process();//netsh work well but i dont want to use
                                        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", "interface ip set address \"" + adapter.Name + "\" dhcp");
                                        p.StartInfo = psi;
                                        p.Start();
```

I expect using EnableDHCP over WMI and IP adress was cleared, but IP adress is still there

[This(Picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4TtP.png)

Comment: You're not showing on what instance (interface) you're trying to invoke that method. Did you hide the rest of the code for a reason?

Comment: That connection has IPAddress and SubnetMask, but no DefaultGateway and no DNS. Not an active connection. The `IPEnabled` property will probably return `false`. See whether the return error code is 84.

Comment: Also, try not to loop all the interfaces and blindly enable the DHCP on all of them. You give the WMI cause to kick you out. Check the interface Caption (the friendly name of the device) or the device ID, or check the IPAddress before trying to change the configuration.

Comment: this code is just for show the error. In original code i sure use selector which port to set :) That connection has param from static before. IPEnabled return true (when he found active port) and after he invoke that metod for EnableDHCP. Akter this connection has enabled DHCP but still somehow remember params from static before.

Comment: This doesn't happen when the new settings have been applied successfully. Read the previous comments. Check for errors, too. That method return and error code, that must be 0. If not, say what error that is. -- If this is not the code you use, then post what you use instead. This code doesn't show any error. You also have an empty exception handler that eats up everything that's eventually thrown. If you post code, post actual code, not a mockup.

Comment: btw if i set static ip after this EnableDHCP .... it will reserve another one params for connection..... and if i do it again it will reserve another one.... so everytime i do switch between DHCP and static by this metod of EnableDHCP you can see one more IPv4 IP and subnet in details of connection and only disable enable help

Answer (score 0):

```
  public Collection<PSObject> Invoke(string Query)
    {
        Collection<PSObject> ps = new Collection<PSObject>();
        try
        {
            using (PowerShell PSI = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                PSI.AddScript(Query);

                ps = PSI.Invoke();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ps = null;

            throw;
        }

        return ps;

    }
```

Create a class to invoke PS Query

```
 public List<YourObjectList> GetInfo(string ParametersIFYouWant)
        {
List<YourObjectList> ListInfo = new List<YourObjectList>();

            InvokePowerShellQuery powerShellQuery = new InvokePowerShellQuery();

            string PSQuery = "Query Here as a string";
            try
            {
                var PSOutput = powerShellQuery.Invoke(PSQuery);
//In your case you wont need unless in you PS Query you return a message or some other object you want to report back for success or failure.
                foreach (var item in PSOutput)
                {
                  //Fill ListInfo 
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Listinfo = null;
                 //handle however you want here
            }

            return Listinfo;
        }
```

Send the query to your class

Quick Google search on PS Queries you may use

https://www.pdq.com/blog/using-powershell-to-set-static-and-dhcp-ip-addresses-part-1/
https://4sysops.com/archives/set-an-ip-address-and-configure-dhcp-with-powershell

Comment: But they say this PS functions is for WIN 8 UP..... I need to change at WIN 7 too :)

Comment: That is in the article, you just need to install Powershell on you computer/server to be able to use some of the Modules in other PS Queries. Check this out to update your PS Version https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-windows-powershell?view=powershell-6